# Problems with this graph. Axes are not correct

Tags: r, histogram

I have four vectors which I'm trying to plot:

```
z1 <- rlnorm(100, meanlog=log(6), sdlog=0.3)
z1 <-ceiling(z1)
s4 <- seq(0,max(z1),0.1) 
d4 <- dlnorm(s4, meanlog=log(6), sdlog=0.3)
hist(z1, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.1), ylim=c(0,max(d4)), xlim=c(0, max(z1)))
par(new=TRUE)

z2 <- rlnorm(100, meanlog=log(4.2), sdlog=log(2.1))
z2 <- ceiling((z2)+15)
s5 <- seq(0,max(z2),0.1) 
d5 <- dlnorm(s5, meanlog=log(4.2), sdlog=log(2.1))
hist(z2, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.15), ylim=c(0,max(d5)), xlim=c(0, max(z2)))
par(new=TRUE)

m1 <- rlnorm(100, meanlog=2, sdlog=0.5)
m1 <- ceiling((m1)+5)
s1 <- seq(0,max(m1),0.1) 
d1 <- dlnorm(s1, meanlog=log(2), sdlog=0.5)
hist(m1, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(0,1,0,alpha=0.1) , ylim=c(0,max(d1)), xlim=c(0, max(m1)))
par(new=TRUE)

m2 <- rnorm(100, mean=16, sd=5)
m2 <- ceiling(m2)
s2 <- seq(0,max(m2),0.1) 
d2 <- dnorm(s2, mean=16, sd=5)
hist(m2, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(0,1,0,alpha=0.15) ,  ylim=c(0,max(d2)), xlim=c(0, max(m2)))
par(new=TRUE)
```

I have problems with plotting this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I9wG.png). 
Axes are not correct.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The first section of your code throws an error because `m1` is not defined. You might want to clean up your code.

Comment: I would compare these groups, but the scale of the graph is wrong. The x axis is now: 5,10,10,20 ..... and y-axis can not be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `add=TRUE` argument to `hist()`, you can plot all your histograms on the same axes.

```
hist(z1, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.1), ylim=c(0,max(d4)), xlim=c(0, max(c(z1,z2, m1, m2))))
hist(z2, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.15), add=T)
hist(m1, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(0,1,0,alpha=0.1), add=T)
hist(m2, prob=T, main="", col=rgb(0,1,0,alpha=0.15), add=T)
```